# Azure price Calc - DR VM from Onprimises to Azure ASR DR

Tags: azure, azure-site-recovery

I have a requirement to move my onprimises azure vms to cloud for only DR.

My current VM has 2012 Server with few applications installed with some critical Roles and the full size of VM is 1TB.

I need your help what are the charges applies and what are the things I should consider for my migration. We just opened a account with Microsoft on Azure nothing is configured and would like to understand the charges that i need to consider for this migration and components that are involved in this task.

Looking for Price calculations and components that are involved for Cost considerations

Answer (score 0):

Learn more on Azure Site Recovery pricing  [Azure Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/site-recovery/?&ef_id=EAIaIQobChMIiILC1br45AIVgpOPCh1fkg9NEAAYASAAEgJrufD_BwE:G:s&OCID=AID2000081_SEM_iACBWjdC&MarinID=iACBWjdC_324588097579_azure%20site%20recovery%20pricing_e_c__62390027934_aud-401542806660:kwd-318783172240&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&dclid=CLapzte6-OQCFSAOtwAdATMGqQ)

If you still find any difficulties in pricing, Free [billing and subscription management support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/options/) has been provided by Microsoft. Feel free to contact us anytime.